# Usage of 合える with verb stems

Tags: grammar, verbs, potential-form

Occasionally I come across an interesting usage of 合える with a verb stem, mostly when I listen to music. One such example can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XgSDZfcq_9o) at approximately 0:42

> 分かり合えない、あなたと私

As far as I can guess, this means "we don't understand each other, you and I"(or lit.: our understanding cannot meet). However, since I couldn't find any useful information using Google, I really can't be sure of it. I would really like to know how common this kind of usage is, and in what situations it would/wouldn't be fitting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

合える is the Potential conjugation of 合う。

> Attaching ~ 合う （あう）to the end of a verb stem means to do the action with each other or to do the action mutually with someone else.

(See more examples on the [source page](http://jvocab-of-the-day.tumblr.com/post/52004228645/grammar-verb-stem-%E5%90%88%E3%81%86))

Attaching `〜合う` and `〜合える` in this way is pretty common.

To determine whether it would be fitting in a certain situation, a good rule of thumb is to ask “Is the verb something you do *to* or *amongst* each other?”

I advise against “*with* each other”, because for example you don't say 「泳{およ}ぎ合う」 to mean “swim with each other”. (In the rare case that it is used, it means more like “swim amongst each other” as if intermingling.)

A few combinations will need special attention as they have a counterintuitive meaning:

> 落{お}ち合う

Does not mean “drop each other”, but to “meet up”.

---

#### Added:

A Japanese friend who is more knowledgeable than me in grammatical terms told me that what I wanted to say in the “rule of thumb” section is better summed up as: “**whether the verb is intransitive (自動詞) or transitive (他動詞)**”. `〜合う` is only attached to transitive verbs.

A great example they gave was the verb **fly**, which can be both intransitive (飛{と}ぶ) and transitive (飛ばす). This explains why you generally don't say 「飛び合う」, but you can say 「飛ばし合う」.

Comment: What are some other verbs ending in 合う which have counterintuitive meanings?

Comment: @jogloran That is a great topic and you may want to post it as a separate question. I said “a few combinations” but that is only relative to the huge number of possible combos, as you can surmise from this incomplete (!) list: http://poppyandbell.cocolog-nifty.com/blog/2011/09/part32part1-147.html

Comment: Isn't it that the original meaning of 落ち合う was a meeting of two rivers and like 合流する is now used to describe "the flow of" people? While in English we say a river "flows into" another, there are European languages in which a river "falls into" another river (which corresponds to 落ちる). When you think this way, it does not seem that much counterintuitive.

Comment: @macraf Yes, and I think there are similarly logical explanations for the other “counterintuitive” ones I had in mind. Maybe I should have said figurative or non-obvious rather than counterintuitive?