# What is the meaning of 及ぼし合う in 人間や生物の周囲にあって，意識や行動の面でそれらと何らかの相互作用を及ぼし合うもの?

Tags: words, parsing, definitions

I was reading the definition of 環境:

> 取り囲んでいる周りの世界。人間や生物の周囲にあって，意識や行動の面でそれらと何らかの相互作用を及ぼし合うもの。

I understand the first sentence it as: "world that is a surrounding-area" or like "the place around us".

I have, however, problems with understanding what the meaning of 及ぼし合う is:

> 人間や生物の周囲にあって，意識や行動の面でそれらと何らかの相互作用を**及ぼし合う**もの。

I know 及ぼす means "to exert (influence)", but with 合う, I know that the action is done with someone. On Yahoo, I found a definition of it 互いに影響しあう. With whom/what is this 及ぼし合う done with?

Comment: How do you understand 面?

Comment: @aguijonazo I understand it as "surface", so "surface of ..."

Comment: But I don't think it makes sense here

Comment: @aguijonazo Do you think it's 面

めん【aspect; phase; perspective; angle】　　　経済面 、資金面、内政面←→外交面、 外面（がいめん）←→内面（ないめん）、表面←→裏面 from http://abacus.bates.edu/~kofuji/StudyResources/kanji.html?

Comment: Yes, that’s the one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core meaning of this type of `masu-stem + 合う` is "mutually". It's typically translated as "each other" or "together" (4th definition [here](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%90%88%E3%81%86)) when the targets are humans, but the targets don't have to be living things. For example, Newton's law of universal gravitation can be explained as すべての物体は引力を及ぼし**あって**いる.

In your sentence, 人間や生物 and 環境 are the two things that exert influences mutually; humans and animals influence the surrounding environment, and vice versa.

- [Usage of 合える with verb stems](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28012/5010)

Comment: Is the と particle after それら ( which is pointing to 人間や生物) indicating who the action is mutually being done with?

Comment: @firuvi Yes, when a verb that normally takes を/に/etc has 合う, it can take と, too. For example, 彼を罵る → 彼と罵り合う, 犬に触れる → 犬と触れ合う.